# How to add Mouse click event in Pine script in trading view?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to add mouse click event to get bar information for selected bar in  traading view.

Answer (score 3):

Can't be done in Pine. There is no visibility on the chart from Pine, and no way for a script to receive UI events other than through changes of inputs in the script's *Settings/Inputs*.